# Open an Modal window from Navigation bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a modal window from navigation bar. I've followed some good tutorials and once I pressed my link a modal opened, problem is model window looks like not editable for some reason, can't even close the X in the modal window. The same works great outside the nav bar.

I would like to know why this happens.

My code is as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Modal Body</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Just a thought. Bootstrap has a special component alignment for navbars. Instead of using pull-right change it to navbar-right.

Align nav links, forms, buttons, or text, using the .navbar-left or .navbar-right utility classes. Both classes will add a CSS float in the specified direction. For example, to align nav links, put them in a separate <ul> with the respective utility class applied.
These classes are mixin-ed versions of .pull-left and .pull-right, but they're scoped to media queries for easier handling of navbar components across device sizes.http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is covered [in the official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> ### Modal markup placement
>
> Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

Put the `<div>` that has the `modal` class outside of the navbar. You can leave the modal-triggering `<a>` in the navbar.

Answer (score 6):

```
<nav class="navbar bg-secondary">
        <div
            class="collapse navbar-collapse float-right" id="navcol-1" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" role="navigation">
                <li><a href="#myModal" data-toggle = "modal" data-target= "#myModal" class="nav-link">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"> 
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">For your Queries</h5> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                IF you have any questions, Mess Manager Office number is <strong>+01234567890</strong> or you can email us by <strong>Ouremail@domain.com</strong>>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing this same issue. The only way I could fix it was by adding a jQuery click on the link in the navbar to override the bootstrap default. Like so:

```
$("#navbar_register_btn").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#basicModal').modal('show');
})
```

You will need to give your link in the navbar an id of "navbar_register_btn" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```