# MVC Modal Popup not working in partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I am using the MVC 5 scaffolded code that generates a `_LoginPartial.cshtml` that comes with the Log in button that redirects to the default login page. However, I am trying to change this so that when I click the button, a login `modal` is pops up instead of redirecting to another page. I modified the code, however it seems to not working as follow:

[image]

When the modal popup, it the whole screen is grey and unable to click anything at all.

The following is the code:

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
   {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
            </li>
        }
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
            Log In
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
}

<!-- Modal -->
div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <section id="loginForm">
                <div id="status" class="text-danger">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "status" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                    <hr />
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("E-mail", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBox("email", "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Password", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.Password("Password", "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, I think it might be because I put the `modal` code in the `partial view` which renders the modal popup to be in a disabled state..any idea why the popup is like that?

Comment: The default form submit button action is redirecting your page. You must intercept this event to prevent default browser behavior.

Comment: @Jasen what do you mean by that? I googled and some suggest is because of the bootstrap modal markup :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685837/open-an-modal-window-from-navigation-bar
However, I could not find a solution to it since it is part of the ``_LoginPartialView``

Comment: Have you tried adding a z-index: 9999 to the Modal?

Comment: Its related to z-index

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the following

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loginModal").("shown.bs.modal",function(){
          $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
        }).on("hide.bs.modal",function(){
          $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
        });
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Had exact same problem as you. My solution is to use the following code after the jQuery Ajax call was successful: `$(".modal-backdrop").remove();`. This will remove your overlay, cause bootstrap adds this overlay on the fly, so the easiest way around this is removing it.